# Applying loop functions with input list of iterators

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

Given an iterator, I am trying to generate a table of all possible pairs of values. The form of the iterator I'd like fixed, because I want to run other loops with it as well. The closest to what I want is below.. For some reason the b value isn't iterated over. What is the reason why? Is there an easier way to implement what I want given any loop function, say Do?

```
iterator = {{a, 0, 4}, {b, 0, 5}};
Table[iterator[[All, 1]], #] & @@ iterator
```

outputting:

```
{{0, b}, {1, b}, {2, b}, {3, b}, {4, b}}
```

**EDIT**

For those who are interested, the reason I want to preserve the iterator as an input is because it seemed the easiest way to iterate through NDEigenvalues in my situation. For an arbitrary potential energy, I am trying to numerically solve for the coefficients that produce a 0 energy ground state in Schrodinger's equation. I want to input the potential, and the range to search over in the coefficient space. The iterator acts as a guessed range based on analytic work. For example,

Input:

```
V[r_] := -Exp[-mS r]/r + a Exp[-mV r]/r;

iterator = {{a, 0.5, 1.5, .1}, {mS, 0.5, 1.5, .1}, {mV, 0.5, 1.5, .1}};
```

program will then take the potential and transform the Schrodinger's eqn into a form easier to use by NDEigenvalues, radialEq. radialEq is a differential equation with parameters a, mS, mV, operating on u[r]. The form of radialEq is why I want to iterate this way. u[r] is transformed to finite domain. So now I have something like:

```
radialEq = V[r] u[r] - 1/2 u''[r]
(* radialEq transformed *)
Do[ev = NDEigenvalues[{radialEq, 
DirichletCondition[u[r] == 0,True]}, u, {r, 0, Pi/2}, 20, (*options*)];
(*appending ground state energy to coefficient-tuple in this round*),
##]&@@iterator;
```

iterator is then updated to refine the search, based on where the 0 evals are found.

The output will be tables of the coefficient~tuples with the ground state energies at different stages of refinement.

Comment: I am not too sure why, but perhaps the following helps: `Table[iterator[[All, 1]], Evaluate[#[[1]]], 
   Evaluate[#[[2]]]] &@iterator`

Comment: Welcome alefs to our Mathematica site. You can see that you got quite some answers to your question. The reason is that although your question is clearly formulated, I and others too are not sure you are handling the underlying problem in the best way Mathematica can provide. One question I had is if you really need explicit iterators because most similar things can be better implemented completely without them. That means I would like to encourage to present an example (like you did!) but let us know *why* you want to do something. You might be surprised what nice different solutions exist.

Comment: Thanks for your responses! I would like to have an iterator as an input because I am working to repeatedly apply NDEigenvalues on Schrodinger's eqn with an inputted potential, numerically solving for the coefficients that produce a 0 energy ground state, and refining that coefficient grid for the next loop. NDEigenvalues takes the differential operator, and i figured the best way to loop over the coefficients was to iterate over them directly. Will provide example

Comment: Did any of the answers satisfied your need? There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. One weeks is enough wait. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [SlotSequence (##)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html) in place of [Slot  (#)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html).

`#` refers to the first element (in your case to `{a, 0, 4}`) in a sequence of slots.

```
Table[iterator[[All, 1]], ##] & @@ iterator
```

> {{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}},
>    {{1, 0}, {1, 
>      1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}},
>    {{2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 
>      3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}},
>    {{3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 
>      5}},
>   {{4, 0}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}}}

Less flexibly, you could also use

```
Table[iterator[[All, 1]], #, #2] & @@ iterator
```

> same result

Answer (score 4):

In case you think you need an explicit `iterator`, let me show how it can be done without one

```
Outer[List, Range[0, 4], Range[0, 5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

...or

```
Table[{a, b}, {a, 0, 4}, {b, 0, 5}];
```

...or

```
Table[{a, b}, Evaluate[iterator[[1]]], Evaluate[iterator[[2]]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

or..

```
Array[List, {5, 6}] - 1
```

> {{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}},
>   {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}},
>   {{2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}},
>   {{3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}},
>   {{4, 0}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}}}

```
Array[List, {5, 6}, {0, 0}]
```